Possible bad bcm
All the lights are on the dash and speedometer not working on 2008 jeep liberty.Codes say pcm and bcm not communicating,can I buy a used 1 with out it having to be reprogrammed? Also is there a way to reset my old one to make sure it’s bad?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
